# How to style the selected item in React-Select when using a custom component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, emotion

We're using a custom Emotion component, and the documentation says that the same properties are passed to customer components, but they don't seem to be. `isSelected` and other properties don't seem to be there either.

```js
const Option = styled.div`
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', Sans-Serif !important;
  font-size: 0.6875rem;
  text-indent: 6px;
  line-height: 1.85;

  &:hover {
    background: #9cbac2;
  }

  ${props => {
    return css`
      background: ${props.isSelected ? 'red' : '#eee'}; // props.isSelected is not defined
    `;
  }}
`;


<Select
  components={{
    Option: ({ children, innerProps, innerRef }) => (
      <Option ref={innerRef} {...innerProps}>
        {children}
      </Option>
    ),
  }}
  styles={reactSelectStyles} // Tried styling Option in the styles object, but that didn't work with a custom component
/>
```

Comment: Could you make an online demo? I'm sure it would be solved very quickly if we can reproduce the total env

Comment: Related styled-components document: [referring-to-other-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isSelected` prop is exposed to the `Option` object, just need to pass it to your `Option` component.

```
<Select
  components={{
    Option: ({ children, innerProps, innerRef, ...rest }) => (
      <Option ref={innerRef} {...innerProps} {...rest}> // isSelected passed with `rest`
        {children}
      </Option>
    )
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit react-codesandboxer-example]